# How does bluealsa's hfp choose audio encoding

Tags: audio, bluetooth, alsa, bluez

bluealsa supports CVSD and mSBC coding. When connecting to other Bluetooth devices, how to determine the coding of hfp.

I know that HFP mandates CVSD support, but I wonder if bluealsa will automatically switch between CVSD and mSBC encoding

Only enter "bluealsa -p hfp-ag-c CVSD" can still connect to the msbc code

Answer (score 0):

*"bluealsa -p hfp-ag-c CVSD"* probably contains a typo and should at least read something like *"bluealsa -p hfp-ag -c CVSD"*. The Codec negotiation takes place when an HFP connection is established. The codec is selected based on runtime conditions and a best-fit approach that is part of the Bluetooth stack.

Comment: Sorry, I typed it wrong. It should be "bluealsa -p hfp-ag -c CVSD".